# What happens if a player hits single one instead of a double with the last dart?

Tags: rules, darts

If a player has one dart to throw and requires two points to win, what happens if they hit a single one instead of a double one?

Comment: What form of darts are you playing? Is is a number countdown (501, 301 etc), or something like cricket? Are there specific rules around finishing on a double?

Answer (score 2):

The [official rules of darts](http://www.pdc.tv/staticFiles/b6/b3/0,,10180~177078,00.pdf) don't make this particularly clear as far as I can tell, but the situation is that reducing your required score to one is the same as going over the required score and the "Bust" rule applies, namely:

> 5.11.03 The “Bust” Rule shall apply, namely if a Player scores more than the number required then that score shall not count and the Player’s score shall revert back to the score the Player had prior to the Opponent’s last throw.